# How to fix "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale" Error in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I want to plot the mean abundance data and standard error data which I calculated in Excel as a bar plot in `ggplot2`. I am getting the error `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale` when I try to plot my data in `gglot2`.

I have tried using an import of the data directly from Excel in Comma Delimited Format (CSV), this did not work so I tried creating my data frame from scratch and the same error appears.

Here is the minimum code required to produce the error. First, I create the column data.

```
Parasite <- c("Heligmosomoides", "Heligmosoma", "Trichuris",
              "Mastophorus", "Auncotheca", "Syphacia", "Tapeworms")
Mean <- c(0.166, 0.053, 0.012, 0.012, 0.0072, 0.287, 0.067)
SE <- c(0.060, 0.036, 0.012, 0.012, 0.042, 0.125, 0.026)
```

Then I created the data frame.

```
DF6 <- data.frame(Parasite, Mean, SE)
```

Then I load up ggplot2.

```
library(ggplot2)
```

Then I used `ggplot2` to create my bar graph with error bars also.

```
BGPA <- ggplot(DF6, aes(x = DF6$Parasite, y = DF6$Mean)) +
    geom_bar(color="black") +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = DF6$Parasite, ymax = DF6$Mean+DF6$SE))
```

And then print it.

```
print(BGPA)
```

This is where I get the error.

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

Comment: In ggplot, get rid of the `DF6$`. And you have `ymin = Parasite`, it should be `ymin = Mean - SE`.

Comment: Try this code: `ggplot(DF6,aes(x=Parasite,y=Mean))+geom_col(color="black")+geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Mean-SE,ymax=Mean+SE))`. Generally, don't use `$` in ggplot aesthetics, as they make use of non-standard evaluation.

Comment: Thank you I have tried what you both recommended and it worked! Error was also me using geom_bar instead of geom_col. Excellent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are setting the `ymin` to `Parasite` instead of `Mean-SE`. Also either use `geom_bar` with `stat = "identity"` or `geom_col`.

```
BGPA <- ggplot(DF6, aes(x = Parasite, y = Mean)) +
    geom_bar(color = "black", stat = "identity") +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean-SE, ymax = Mean+SE))
BGPA
```

Comment: This is all correct except I removed the negative SE for aesthetic purposes. Thank you for letting me know about how to use geom_bar correctly!

Comment: No worries. And if you want to remove the lower SE, then just use `ymin = Mean`.